# extjs 3.4 get progressbar html representation before it's rendered

Tags: javascript, extjs, progress-bar

I would like to know if there is any way to get html representation of progressbar before it's rendered anywhere?

I need to render progressbar in a grid. As for now I use custom renderer for progress column:

```
renderer: function( value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store ) {
                var id = Ext.id();
                (function(){
                    var progress = new Ext.ProgressBar({
                        renderTo: id,
                        value: progress_value
                    });
                }).defer(50);
                return '<div id="'+ id + '"></div>';
            }
```

But it doesn't look user friendly, because progressbars render after grid has been rendered.

I think that it's possible to create custom progressbar with this functionality as one can see template source code that is rendered into html, but it's not so elegant I think.

The best thing would be create function like this, I think:

```
var generateRenderer = (function(){
        var pb = new Ext.ProgressBar();
        return function( progress_value ){
            pb.updateValue( progress_value );
            return pb.htmlRepresentationFunction();
        }
    })();
```

Where `htmlRepresentationFunction()` is the function that returns html represetation (as obvious from it's name). And then use `generateRenderer()` function in custom renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now I've rewritten the code this way:

```
progressBarHtmlGenerator: (function(){
    var width = progress_width,
        cls = 'x-progress', // it's default class from ext.js
        tpl = new Ext.Template( // this template is from ProgressBar.js in ext.js
            '<div class="{cls}-wrap">',
                '<div class="{cls}-inner">',
                    '<div class="{cls}-bar" style="width: {barWidth}px">',
                        '<div class="{cls}-text">',
                            '<div>{text}</div>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="{cls}-text {cls}-text-back">',
                        '<div>{textBack}</div>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>'
        );
    return function(value, text, textBack){
        return tpl.apply({
            cls: cls,
            barWidth: value*width || 0,
            text: text || '&#160;',
            textBack: textBack || '&#160;'
        })
    }
})()
```

This template is from ProgressBar.js. And then I use this function in my custom renderer like this:

```
renderer: function( value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store ) {
                var value = progress_value;
                return this.progressBarHtmlGenerator(value);
            }.createDelegate(this)
```

So as I don't need animation it works, but still I hope there is some way much more elegant than this one.